# regex error(Java::JavaLang::ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4) on 3 character non-english strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

The following steps reproduce the error. Any workarounds/fixes? Thanks.
Also this happens with

> jruby 1.5.2/rails 2.3.9 and jruby 1.6/rails 3.0.5

```
regex = /(aaa|bbb):/
str = "\343\202\242:"
str =~ regex
```

Steps in action.

```
d:\myapp>jruby script/rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.5)
irb(main):001:0> regex = /(aaa|bbb):/
=> /(aaa|bbb):/
irb(main):002:0> str = "\343\202\242:"
=> "péó:"
irb(main):003:0> str =~ regex
Java::JavaLang::ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
        from org.jcodings.MultiByteEncoding.safeLengthForUptoFour(MultiByteEncoding.java:5
        from org.jcodings.specific.NonStrictUTF8Encoding.length(NonStrictUTF8Encoding.java
        from org.joni.Matcher.forwardSearchRange(Matcher.java:124)
        from org.joni.Matcher.search(Matcher.java:432)
        from org.jruby.RubyRegexp.search(RubyRegexp.java:1474)
        from org.jruby.RubyRegexp.op_match(RubyRegexp.java:1391)
        from org.jruby.RubyString.op_match(RubyString.java:1557)
        from org.jruby.RubyString$i$1$0$op_match.call(RubyString$i$1$0$op_match.gen:65535)
        from org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:
        from org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:139)
        from org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
        from org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:103)
        from org.jruby.ast.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:129)
        from org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_EVAL(ASTInterpreter.java:95)
        from org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.evalWithBinding(ASTInterpreter.java:160)
        from org.jruby.RubyKernel.evalCommon(RubyKernel.java:1134)
... 158 levels...
        from org.jruby.RubyKernel$s$1$0$require.call(RubyKernel$s$1$0$require.gen:65535)
        from org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(Java
        from org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:61)
        from org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:61)
        from org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:
        from org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:139)
        from script.rails.__file__(script/rails:6)
        from script.rails.load(script/rails)
        from org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:670)
        from org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:574)
        from org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:423)
        from org.jruby.Main.doRunFromMain(Main.java:278)
        from org.jruby.Main.internalRun(Main.java:198)
        from org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:164)
        from org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:148)
        from org.jruby.Main.main(Main.java:128)irb(main):004:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the regex is not delimited.

How about

str =~ /(aaa|bbb):/

or

regex='(aaa|bbb):'

str =~ /regex/

Comment: With str =~ /regex/ the Regex is /regex/ not /(aaa|bbb):/ as regex is not replaced with its value.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you're passing a string that contains multibyte characters you need to pass the /u regex parameter to parse it as a UTF-8 string.

Just checked this in different versions of Ruby and it only appears to happen in JRuby so I think you've found a bug ;)

If you use something like "string".to_java_string first it would appear to work but it's actually converting it to ISO-8859-1 first which you don't want. To maintain your encoding just use .to_java and pass it the regex.

Here's a work around that should work I think:

```
regex = /(aaa|bbb):/u
str = "\343\202\242:"
str.to_java =~ regex
```